# Trying to log JSON response in terminal using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, graphql-js, k6

When I type the following command

```
console.log("Response = " +JSON.stringify(response.body));
```

I get the following response

```
Response = {"data":{"getPortalByOrganizationAliasAndSlug":{"portalId":"123f3redvq","expireAt":null,"accountId":"1","templateId":"stephendemo","arePortalDefaultsOverriden":null,"template":{"allContent":null,"digitalAssets":[],"recommendedContent":null,"allTopics":null,"recommendedTopics":null,"templateId":"stephendemo","organizationId":"fqewf2134214","header":"","footer":"","favicon":"null","logoPath":"/img/pages/logo.png","logo":"https://dev-v3-23-dev-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/r232r/232332/3232/stephendemo/image-logo-1603086511.png","primaryColor":"undefined","secondaryColor":"#b5b3b3","labels":{"key":"key","value":"value","__typename":"Tuple"},"orgLegalName":"Stephen Carvalho","supportTextLine":"Support","supportEmailAddress":null,"termsOfService":"http://2323.com","copyright":"Stephen Carvalho","invitationDelivery":"MANUALLY","magicLink":false,"emailAndPAssword":false,"scope":"2332","searchPlaceholder":"search","inputPlaceholder":null,"orgDisplayName":"Stephen","styles":{"contentCards":{"type":"STANDARD","__typename":"ContentCardStyle"},"__typename":"TemplateStyles"},"__typename":"TemplatePortalContent"},"templateBuyerPortal":null,"driftEnabled":false,"driftConfig":null,"portalState":"enabled","portalSlug":"stephendemo","userOwnerId":"1","userOwner":{"organizationId":"oSvjLe1paYKg","firstName":"Stephen","lastName":"Carvalho","email":"stephen.omedym+stephensdemo@gmail.com","accountId":"1","portalIds":null,"phone":null,"title":null,"__typename":"User"},"teamMembers":null,"organizationAlias":"stephensdemo","companyId":1,"organizationId":"oSvjLe1paYKg","scope":"CONTENT_PORTAL","isContentPortalv3":true,"landingPageUrl":null,"isLandingPageUrlEnabled":false,"blockedDomains":[],"exclusiveContent":{"digitalAssets":[{"id":"2","status":5,"__typename":"ExclusiveDigitalAsset"}],"__typename":"ExclusiveContentType"},"__typename":"Portal"}}}  source=console
```

I want to save the portal id in a variable.

I tried this command to first print only the part from the data variable

```
let responsedata = JSON.parse(response.body.data);
 console.log(responsedata);
```

But I get the following error

```
ERRO[0002] SyntaxError: invalid character 'u' looking for beginning of value
running at parse (native)
```

Even if I try the following command I get the same error

```
let responsedata = JSON.parse(response.body.data.getPortalByOrganizationAliasAndSlug.portalId);
console.log(responsedata);
```

Could anyone help me understand how do I print the variables inside the response such as the values of portalID or accounted?

Comment: response.body.data vs response.body ... just parse 2nd one if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse the value inside your json and not the json response body. Try the below code.

```
let responsedata = JSON.parse(response.body).data;
console.log(responsedata);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe the `response.body` is already parsed.
and `JSON.stringify(response.body)` converts it again to JSON and valid json is printed to console.

try logging `response.body`without `JSON.stringify()` and see if it prints a javascript object.

If it does, There is no need to `JSON.parse(response.body.data)`.
Use it as you would normally use a javascript object.